# Yosemite corrupted texture in Mission Control

Tags: macos, display, macbook-pro, graphics, mission-control

When I fire up Mission Control, there are some corrupted textures ("glitch") overlaying Unity3D window. The texture is different each time I enter Mission Control, and they are related to what other programs I'm using. After I switched to Unity window, the corrupted textures disappear. I'm using the 15in MacBook Pro with Retina Display Late 2013 with dedicated graphics.

I've also seen corrupted graphics in Yosemite Safari and Preview after waking up from sleep with external monitor, and zooming makes them disappear.

Is it a Yosemite bug or a hardware defect?

Some samples:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

From System Information:

```
NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M:

  Chipset Model:    NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M
  Type: GPU
  Bus:  PCIe
  PCIe Lane Width:  x8
  VRAM (Total): 2048 MB
  Vendor:   NVIDIA (0x10de)
  Device ID:    0x0fe9
  Revision ID:  0x00a2
  ROM Revision: 3776
  gMux Version: 4.0.8 [3.2.8]
  Displays:
Color LCD:
  Display Type: Retina LCD
  Resolution:   2880 x 1800 Retina
  Retina:   Yes
  Pixel Depth:  32-Bit Color (ARGB8888)
  Main Display: Yes
  Mirror:   Off
  Online:   Yes
  Built-In: Yes
ASUS PB287Q:
  Resolution:   3840 x 2160 @ 60 Hz
  Pixel Depth:  32-Bit Color (ARGB8888)
  Mirror:   Off
  Online:   Yes
  Rotation: Supported
  Connection Type:  DisplayPort
  Television:   Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your specifications I am guessing that you are using a MacBook Pro with Retina Display. I have heard about glitches with ones that have a dedicated GPU because OS X actually used both the integrated and the dedicated side by side. To fix this problem you are probably going to want to reset your SMC (System Management Controller) which controls these things.

Step 1 : Shut down your MacBook.

Step 2 : Connect the MagSafe power adapter into your MacBook. If it’s already connected, leave as is.

Step 3 : Press Shift + Control + Option + Power keys at the same time.

Step 4 : Release all the keys from the keyboard.

Step 5 :  Press the power button to start your MacBook.

Comment: Resetting SMC and NVRAM doesn't solve the problem. I'm more inclined to suspect that it's a problem with the OS.